# Open a SMTP connection

Tags: java, sockets, email, smtp

How to use socket to setup a SMTP server? I don't want to use any library like WISER. I just want a very simple SMTP server. How to setup?
I have tried to use the following code. But it seems like wrong.

```
try {
        // TODO code application logic here
        InetSocketAddress isa = new InetSocketAddress(25);
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket();
        server.bind(isa);
        System.out.println("Server starting...");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            Socket client = server.accept();
            if (client != null) {
                System.out.println("connected");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Fakeserver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: All you have is the first step, and it is not wrong, but all it does is opens a listening socket, accepts client connections on it, and disconnects them immediately.  Now you need to move each of those clients to their own worker threads, and then have each thread exchange SMTP commands and responses with its respective client.  Have you read the SMTP protocol specifications yet?  Look at [RFC 5321](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321) and maybe also [RFC 2554](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4954) and other related RFCs.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "simple SMTP server".  Properly implementing the SMTP protocol such that you can actually send and receive mail is a huge job.Helping you do this from where you seem to be at this point is far, far beyond the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: What does _"it seems like wrong"_ mean? Does it throw an error? Then give us the error message, or better the whole stack trace. Or it just writes nothing (it should at least write `Server starting...` and then `Waiting...`) to the console? Elaborate.